# How can I restart my server using a request api

Tags: python, api

so I have a server and did an api for it so I can update patch files to my server, however now when I update the some batch files in the server, I always have to stop running the server and than run it again to see the changes, I was wondering what can I do so that my server restart it's self

Comment: You'll want to specify your server's operating system first. This will tell us what is available to you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,
Make requests api send a json like `{'do': 'refresh_server'}-`
then just type exit(), then run the file again using the os module.

Edit: This is solution for windows

Comment: I would recommend you to add security so that no-one randomly shuts down the server.

Comment: hi sorry for not specifying enough, so my api changes in the setting and core stuff in the program as whole, so i need to kill the cmd process that is running the server (runserver.py) and then start again, i cant send a json file throw the api because the api to send a patch file for updates.
what i thought to do is to run cmd and navigate to the runserver.py and run it again. so far this is what i got 
os.system("start /B start cmd.exe @cmd /k cd ../../../..")
i tried to append the command python runserver.py to the command one line above and it didnt work , thank you in advance

Comment: This may not work if you call exit () before you ran the file again.

Comment: Since it will instantly terminate the code. Call it from another file like refresh.py

Comment: hi thank you so much i found a solution for now, it is not the best but it will do for now, thank you so much again for your advice

Comment: @mon How did you solve the problem? Can you share? I have same problem right now.